# if cell contains certain number then copy

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, copy

A simple explanation of what I am having troubles with:

Sheet 1 Column A: List of 39130 order numbers
Sheet 1 Column B: tax number associated to Column A
Sheet 2 Column A: List of 24 different numbers  with same values as Sheet 1 Column B
Sheet 2 Column B: A list of tax numbers

So, I'm looking to search sheet 1 column A for a value that matches sheet 2 column A, and return the value of Sheet 2 Column be in a new column (G)

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

On Sheet 2 field G1 should have the following formula. That should do the job:
=VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet1!$A:$B;2;0)